# Can not access an EXCEL file on a 64-Bit Windows 7 with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, excel, 64-bit

my Windows 7 is 64 bit. My Visual Studio project is target to x86. I have installed this:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&displaylang=en#Requirements (the x32 version).

I get this error message: `The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.`

What do I wrong?

Comment: It didn't install properly.  Ask for help at superuser.com

Comment: why do you think it did not install properly?

Answer (score 0):

When you build the project you need to specify that you're specifically targeting x86 CPUs, not Any CPU.

I don't have VS 2010 installed here, so can't tell you exactly what to do, but either . . .

From the drop down that says "Any CPU" select x86.

Or on your project properties page (of the exe project) select "x86" for "Platform Target"

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at 32-bit Microsoft ODBC Administrator to register the 32-bit driver. The one under Adminsitrative Tools is 64-bit only.  Go to Windows\System32\, the search for odbcad32.exe. Click on System DSN, and register the 32-bit driver.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable" in Win 7 64 bit without any issue. Try to install 64 bit version of "Access Database Engine".

I've got the following configuration
Win 7 64 bit
VS 2010 32 bit (there is no 64 bit)
Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable 64 bit

Cheers...

Muse Extensions